# Dropdown list is not populating from items collection

Tags: excel, vba

Note: This is not my original code.
I need help populating dropdown list in excel sheet1 from a collection I created using data in columns F & G of sheet2. I also need help eliminating duplicates from the total list. Debug.print displays all items in the collein withction but dropdown list validation results in display of only first item from sheet2 columns in cell B6 on sheet1 set to be dropdown list.  Each item in Sheet2 columns F&G is of the fornat .  Here is the code I have so far, courtesy several snippets posted on this site and explained in many others. Thanks to them for relevant code snippets. My code does not include duplicate elimination as yet because I am lost on populating the dropdown list, to begin with.

Thanks

```
Sub MonitorNames()
Dim s As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim nr As Long
Dim wr As Range, v, p
Dim c As Collection
Dim i As Integer

Set c = New Collection
Set wr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1:G180")
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & 6) = ""

nr = wr.Rows.Count
s = ""

For r = 3 To nr
    v = wr(r, 1)
    p = wr(r, 2)
    s = v & "," & p
    c.Add s
Next

Range("B" & 6).Select 'This is in sheet1

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
Debug.Print c.Item(1)
Debug.Print c.Item(c.Count)
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=c.Item(1), Formula2:=c.Item(c.Count)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
'    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make a DV dropdown is from a **comma-separated string**.  For example:

```
Sub InternalString()

    With Range("B2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="alpha,beta,gamma,delta"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

and we can make the string from a range or an internal VBA array, or a Collection:

```
Sub DVfromCollection()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    c.Add "Larry"
    c.Add "Moe"
    c.Add "Curley"
'*********************************************************
    Dim s As String
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        s = c.Item(i) & IIf(s = "", "", ",") & s
    Next i
    With Range("C2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=s
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gary's Student!  The dropdown list is now populating but the first and last names do not show in the format <firstname,lastname>.  These are now showing as <lastname> below the <firstname>.

Comment: @Ven  We must be clever when building the comma-separated string......must look like:  **Darth Vader,John Galt,Jack Kemp,Jim Ravenswood,Jakobshavn Isbrae**

Comment: You are right, Gary's Student!   I just learnt and got the list drop down.  Quick question.  Is there a way to sort this collection by the First Name (or last name) once its done?

Comment: @Ven  Consider creating an `ArrayList`..............I believe it has native Sort ability.

Comment: I will look not that, @Gary's Student.  Dropdown list  validation results a string in which the second name is added to the first and third to the second and so on.  The net result is a dropdown list ordered in descending (Z-A) order rather then the other way I had hoped to create.  I do not know about ArrayLists but will look into it.  Thank you for pointing me in that direction.